# How to set agent status to 'Logged out' when unregister

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch

Is there any way to change Agent status to something else when he unregister?

For reference

> > https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_callcenter#status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on event. U have to write a process that will connect to freeswitch through ESL. There put a event handler for unregister event. based on that event you can change the status of any agent to anything you want

Comment: you are right. This was exactly I did. I should have shared answer myselft. Felt noone cared about this.